# How to determine what classes are causing Finalizer memory leak

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, finalizer, yourkit

I am using yourkit java profiler to try and determine where my memory leak is coming from.  I think it is from a large number of java.lang.ref.finalizer objects not being collected/processed fast enough.  None of the code I have written implements the finalize method, but I am using several libraries that may.  Is there a way in yourkit or other means to determine what objects are not being finalized?